# argument returns Undefined when trying to save in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is the function I've created to generate a notification key after getting the data from firestore. the notification key is generated successfully for a new user, but comes to be "undefined" when trying to set it in the firestore.

I've commented out my problem related to the issue in the following code.

index.js

```
exports.saveGroups = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}").onWrite((change,context) => {

const token_id1 = change.after.data().token_id;
const token_email = change.after.data().email;
const image = change.after.data().image;
const name1 = change.after.data().name;
const key = change.after.data().notification_key;
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
console.log('token_id is: ' + token_id1);
console.log('token_email is:' + token_email); 
console.log('user_id is:' + user_id); 

if (key === undefined) {
    console.log('key was not present, hence create');
    var options = {
        url: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    json: {'operation': 'create',
    'notification_key_name': token_email,
    'registration_ids': [token_id1]}
    }

    request(options,function (error, response, body) {
       tokenName = body.notification_key;      //here i get the notification_key successfully

        return console.log(tokenName);

    });

     var data = {

                image: image,
                email: token_email,
                name: name1,
                notification_key: tokenName,       // this field becomes undefined while saving to firestore
                token_id: token_id1,
                extra: 'created'

             };
             console.log('image : ' + image);
             console.log('email : ' + token_email);
             console.log('name : ' + name1);
             console.log('tokenName : ' + tokenName);
             console.log('token_id : ' + token_id1);

             var setDoc = db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set(data);
}else{
    console.log('key is present , do not create but add');
 }
```

[image: Shows Undefined]

[image]

Comment: its still not working. it's still coming to be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

What if you declare the variable `tokenName` before calling `request()`?

```
exports.saveGroups = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}").onWrite((change,context) => {

const token_id1 = change.after.data().token_id;
const token_email = change.after.data().email;
const image = change.after.data().image;
const name1 = change.after.data().name;
const key = change.after.data().notification_key;
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
console.log('token_id is: ' + token_id1);
console.log('token_email is:' + token_email); 
console.log('user_id is:' + user_id); 

if (key === undefined) {
    console.log('key was not present, hence create');
    var options = {
        url: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    json: {'operation': 'create',
    'notification_key_name': token_email,
    'registration_ids': [token_id1]}
    }

    let tokenName = "";

    return request(options,function (error, response, body) {

       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           tokenName = body.notification_key;

         var data = {

                image: image,
                email: token_email,
                name: name1,
                notification_key: tokenName, 
                token_id: token_id1,
                extra: 'created'

             };
             console.log('image : ' + image);
             console.log('email : ' + token_email);
             console.log('name : ' + name1);
             console.log('tokenName : ' + tokenName);
             console.log('token_id : ' + token_id1);

             return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set(data);


       } else {

             return false;

       }     

}else{
    console.log('key is present , do not create but add');
    return false;
 }
```

The reason of your problem is variable scoping. See http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html

Comment: i tried it. now the the tokenName is coming to be "". its not going inside the request.

Comment: Are you sure it is **not** going inside the request? Or it is the request that does not work as expected?

Comment: it is returning me notification_key : " " in the firestore but displays it in the log successfully. also its setting the "data" to the firestore first and then calling the request

Comment: if you change `return console.log(tokenName);`
 to `console.log("tokenName -> "tokenName);`
 into the request, what do you see? Note that the `return` is removed.

Comment: Also note that I have edited my answer and changed `var setDoc = db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set(data);` to `return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set(data);`. A Cloud Function shall return a promise.

Comment: I've uploaded the output image of the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172001/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-rituparna).